# Power Apps - How to change the format of the Rich text column to normal text of the Data Table object

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have created a power app form and showing a data from a list using data table object in power apps.Currently Data shows html tag along with the data. I want to change the format of the Rich text column to normal text of the Data Table object. I cannot change the SharePoint column to single line text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data table currently cannot be customized to do what you want; one option is to use a gallery, where you have full control over the controls (no pun intended) that are used to display the rows from your data source. If you use a gallery, you can then add the rich text editor (or the Html Text control, for read-only scenarios) in the gallery and bind it to the rich text column from SharePoint.

Comment: can you please provide any reference saying we can have rich text editor for read only scenarios and not as a user input in a gallery

Comment: You **can** have the rich text editor for user input in a gallery. What I said was that if you don't want to allow the user to edit the HTML text, then you use the Html Text control, that only displays it.

Comment: Ohh but I am trying since morning and not able to add rich text editor as user input in gallery

Comment: Ah, you're correct, I take that back. The rich text editor cannot be used in a gallery. There are a few controls that have this limitation, such as forms, and it seems like the rich text editor is one of them.